# Finding methods in a ClassOrInterface Declaration

Tags: java, javaparser

Is there any way I can find the methods in a ClassOrInterface Declaration?

I'm using javaparser to read in source code which but when I read in multiple classes I have the problem of trying to attach which methods are attached to which classes.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this? Is there any sort of

```
class1.getMethods();
```

which would return a list of MethodDeclaration's that are in that class? Alternatively is there a way that I a MethodDeclaration can return the name of the Class that it is in?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what exactly is your requirement 
but if you want to see a class's methods and variables including private one's, then see java [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: javaparser is a parser for java *source code*. Reflection won't help here.

Comment: The only way i know is this -->                                 Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();

Comment: @sumitjain That's it thank you ! Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]); Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods(); returns it ! perfect thanks a lot!